# Can we merge arrays inside Current parent array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

my main array name is $constant...

```
   $constants = array(
    'residential' => array(
        "flat" => "Flat", "swimming_pool" => "Swimming pool",
                 "hall" => "Hall", "garden" => "Garden", "clubhouse" => "Clubhouse"
    ),'commercial' => array(
            "shop" => "Shop", "office" => "Office"
),);
```

i can merge this array using array_merge like

```
$result = array_merge($constants['residential'],$constants['commercial']);
```

but i want to merge this array where i declare that array like..

```
$constants = array(
'residential' => array(
    "flat" => "Flat", "swimming_pool" => "Swimming pool",
             "hall" => "Hall", "garden" => "Garden", "clubhouse" => "Clubhouse"
),'commercial' => array(
            "shop" => "Shop", "office" => "Office"
), 
'test' => array_merge('residential','commercial'));
```

is that possible please help.....

Comment: WHat should be the final array?

Comment: test array holds all values of residential and commercial array..

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible - you can't use values from the array that is just in the process of being declared, so the way to do it is similar to your first code snippet:

```
$constants = array(
    'society_types' => array(
        "residential"=>"Residential", "commercial"=>"Commercial", "resicumcomm" => "Residential cum Commercial"
    ),
    'residential' => array(
        "flat" => "Flat", "swimming_pool" => "Swimming pool", "hall" => "Hall", "garden" => "Garden", "clubhouse" => "Clubhouse"
    )
);

$constants['test'] = array_merge($constants['society_types'], $constants['residential']);
```